# iOS NSDate Core Data Compare fetch request not working

Tags: core-data, crash, compare, nsdate, nspredicate

maybe you can help me. What is wrong with this code:

```
-(NSMutableArray *)returnItemsWithName:(NSString *)name{

    NSFetchRequest *fetch=[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity=[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"XYZ" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
    [fetch setEntity:entity];
    NSDate *sevenDaysAgo = [appDelegate dateByAddingDays:-7 toDate:[NSDate date]];
NSPredicate *pred= [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"originTime >= %@", sevenDaysAgo]];
    [fetch setPredicate:pred];
    NSError *fetchError=nil;
    NSMutableArray *fetchedObjs = [[[self managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:fetch error:&fetchError] retain];
    if (fetchError!=nil) {
        return nil;
    }

    return fetchedObjs;

}
```

the line

```
fetchedObjs = [[[self managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:fetch error:&fetchError] retain];
```

crashes with the error:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "originTime >= 2011-02-28 21:07:37 +0000"'

All the objects are NOT nil and also originDate is a NSDate in the CD database

Comment: Is the name of the field "originDate" or "originTime"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your problem is this:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"originTime >= %@", sevenDaysAgo]];
```

`predicateWithFormat:` *already* wants a format string.  It is unnecessary and, as you've found, wrong to do what you're doing.  It's pretty easy to fix though:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"originTime >= %@", sevenDaysAgo];
```

That will work just fine.

Comment: is 'originTime' here an attribute with type NSDate? If yes how did the predicate with format work out? 

shouldn't we use the 'laterDate:' function? does the '>' and '<' operators work for dates?